# JQuery resize() on window scale up or scale down

Tags: jquery, responsive-design

I have this code which shows/hides a menu when a button is cicked

```
$('#main-menu ul').slideToggle();
```

the menu is hidden when the browser window is less than 767 px, so this button appears which allows it to be toggled on and off,  this works except the only problem is when I resize the window bigger again, the menu is gone, if slide toggled has set it to display none. to fix this I added code to show the menu once the browser resizes.  this then causes the new menu to show, when the browser window is scaled down again less than 767 px, instead of having the default be hidden. I can then hide the menu again when scaled less than 767px but this causes a flash of the menu as it is hidden.

I was wondering a way to detect if resize() was scaling up r down in this case when scaling down I can hide() menu and when scaling up I can show() menu.

```
$('.menu-button').click(function() {
    $('#main-menu ul').slideToggle();
});



    $(window).resize(function(){
                var w = $(window).width();
                if(w > 767 && $('#main-menu ul').is(':hidden')) {
                    $('#main-menu ul').show();
                }
            });




    $(window).resize(function(){
                var w = $(window).width();
                if(w < 767) {
                    $('#main-menu ul').hide();
                }
            });
```

Comment: why aren't you just using css to hide and show based on screen witdh? Also, you don't need to add 2 listeners. Just put your w < 767 in a conditional in the first listener

Comment: I am creating a button that toggles the menu giving user to show or hide when the browser is < 767

Comment: you can just show the button if less than 767 and on click add class to the menu that overwrites the media query declaration. Unless you really want the animations, which is pretty much the only reason to use jquery for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to store the previous dimensions and decide whether the resize is increasing or decreasing in size based on that.

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Cache a reference to $(window), for performance, and get the initial dimensions of the window
    var $window = $(window),
        previousDimensions = {
            width: $window.width(),
            height: $window.height()
        };

    $window.resize(function(e) {
        var newDimensions = {
            width: $window.width(),
            height: $window.height()
        };

        if (newDimensions.width > previousDimensions.width) {
            // scaling up
        } else {
            // scaling down
        }

        // Store the new dimensions
        previousDimensions = newDimensions;
    });
});
```

To keep the menu visible when the browser window is resized and the user's chosen to display it, you'll just need to store a flag stating that the user chose to make it visible:

```
$('.menu-toggle-button').click(function(e) {
    var $menu = $('#main-menu ul');

    if (!$menu.data('keepVisible')) {
        $menu
            .data('keepVisible', true); // Store the user's choice (show the menu)
            .slideDown(); // Show the menu
    } else {
        $menu
            .data('keepVisible', false); // Store the user's choice (hide the menu)
            .slideUp(); // Hide the menu
    }
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    var $menu = $('#main-menu ul');

    if ($(window).width() < 767) {
        // Window is smaller than 767 pixels wide
        if (!$menu.data('keepVisible')) {
            // Hide the menu if it hasn't been kept visible by the user
            $menu.hide();
        }
    } else if ($menu.is(':hidden') || $menu.data('keepVisible')) {
        Window is larger than 767 pixels wide and the menu is invisible OR has been shown manually by the user
        $menu
            .data('keepVisible', false) // Reset the user's choice
            .show(); // Show the menu
    }
);
```

(Note that with this technique, the code block that determines if the window got bigger or smaller is completely unnecessary)

Comment: what is the point of this?  previousDimensions = newDimensions;

Comment: unfortunately that still gives a flash of the menu for me when scaling down.

Comment: @alex_b The point of previousDimensions = newDimensions is to store the current dimensions of the window after resizing has taken place, so on the next resize event we can determine if the window was made bigger or smaller relative to the last time it was resized. Regarding the flash, the second block of code I added with my last edit should actually be all you need to accomplish what you're trying to do

Comment: @alex_b My most recent edit fixes an issue where the menu would always stay visible if it was manually shown until the button was clicked again, even if the window was resized

Answer (score 2):

The answer Kelvin Mackay provided works, but is it a little bit verbose for something quite simple? Why does it matter whether you are scaling up or scacling down, all the question really cares about is one point, 767px, that is the only determinig factor and all that needs to be done, is alter visibility.

If you are using responsive UI principles, which are really more to do with handling layouts across multiple devices rather than people resize their browser window, why are you even needing a button to hide/display the menu. Its should just automatically happen based on the screen size.

Firstly, when the page loads, you will need to determine the menu state, then all you need to do is have a resize handler which you have (if you simply combine the two and why worry about whether the menu is already hidden):

```
   $(window).resize(function(){
            var w = $(window).width();
            if(w > 767) {
                $('#main-menu ul').show();
            }
            else {
                $('#main-menu ul').hide();
            }
        });
```

EDIT:
It's a long time since this answer, if you were to do this now, you should be doing this type of thing inside `requestAnimationFrame`.